# Screen brightness 100% with proprietary Nvidia driver

Tags: debian, xorg, nvidia, brightness, proprietary-drivers

After having installed the proprietary Nvidia driver on Debian Jessie in order to play Steam games (which I now can), I can't change the brightness at all, it is stuck at the maximum and is irritating my eyes at night. I have already tried all of the solutions in the Debian [wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers)

such as adding the line: `Option         "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1;"` to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-nvidia.conf`

but that has not worked, even though in the [Debian forums](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=106078) it seems to work (marked solved):

xbacklight does not work at all, and I don't know what to do anymore. I will post any outputs for whatever terminal commands, please help.

Comment: How about `xrandr --output LVDS1 --brightness 0.4` (put your display instead of lvds1 if needed)?

Comment: `xrandr --output LVDS-0 --brightness 0.2` works! It doesn't seem to change the brightness at the hardware level, but it will save my eyes! Thanks to user jimmij!

Comment: Yes, this is software change, and `echo 2 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness` doesn't work? (again change `acpi_video0` to your device like intel_backlight etc.).

Comment: When I do `sudo echo 2 > /sys/class/backlight/asus-nb-wmi/brightness` I get: `bash: /sys/class/backlight/asus-nb-wmi/brightness: Permission denied`

Comment: Try running `sudo -s` then the eco. Sudo doesn't work over piped echos in the way described. You need to do `echo "moo"  | sudo tee /patch/to/file.txt`

Answer (score 6):

After adding the following line in your X device configuration

```
Option  "RegistryDwords"  "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
```

You can use the software xbacklight to adjust the brightness:

```
xbacklight -set 60
```

Comment: Added that option to my /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-nvidia.conf in Debian 8 and now everything works normally in KDE

Comment: Seems KDE is more forgiving than gnome, FWIW https://askubuntu.com/a/1152763/20972

Answer (score 2):

Complementing [@semente](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/322862/288558) answer:

```
xbacklight +10
xbacklight -10
```

increase and decrease the backlight in steps of 10%. They can be associated to keys with `xbindkeys` by following the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/257497/678974). Below is sample of the `.xbindkeysrc` with this commands associated to the <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>Windows</kbd> +  <kbd>F6</kbd> keys:

```
"xbacklight +10"
 Mod4 + F6

"xbacklight -10"
 Mod4 + F5
```

Answer (score 1):

I followed this tutorial to install NVidia driver for linux from NVidia:

http://allaboutlinux.eu/remove-nouveau-and-install-nvidia-driver-in-debian-8/2/

and now I have NVIDIA X Server Settings GUI which can be launched from applications drawer, then I go to GPU 0 --> CRT-0 --> Color Correction and I'm able to set brightness to negative value.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't change the backlight brightness.

Comment: thanks for this color correction settings, i didn't know that @TimRichardson, you could use ```xrandr --output HDMI-0 --brightness  0.7``` change the HDMI-0 with your monitor